# How to iterate through two arrays and return key values to different object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const phoneBook = {};
const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];
const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675']

function populate(names, numbers) {
  for(i = 0; i < populate.length; i++) {
    phoneBook[names[i]] = numbers[i];
}
  
}
```

How can I get my for loop to iterate through both arrays simultaneously and return names as a key and numbers as the values?

Comment: You probably want to put `return phoneBook` at the end of the function? And, perhaps you want to check `names.length` or `numbers.length` in the for loop, instead of `populate.length` (I don't know what `populate` is)

Comment: `populate` is your function. `populate.length` is `2` (the number of non-optional arguments) and is unrelated to your arrays. Make sure you actually call the function.

Comment: populate is the function that is taking the two arrays as parameters. My thinking was that if I iterate through the function(populate) it will be the same as iterating through the two arrays separately.

Comment: @larryfly _“My thinking was that if I iterate through the function(populate) it will be the same as iterating through the two arrays separately”_ — Not sure where you got that idea from… No. `populate.length` is the [function’s length](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

Comment: @SebastianSimon so to iterate through both names and numbers in the same for loop can I just do I < names.length && numbers.length

Comment: The length of `names` should be the same as the length of `numbers`, right? So you can just pick one, since they're both the same number. (`&&` won't do what you want either, just do one or the other, it doesn't matter which).

Comment: i.e. if there's 5 items in the names array, and 5 items in the numbers array, you're going to want to run the body of the loop 5 times, 1 time for each item in both of those arrays. So, that's why you loop from 0 to `names.length`, or from 0 to `numbers.length`

Comment: @SebastianSimon I see what you mean. So I changed populate.length to names.length. Still getting undefined when I console log console.log(phoneBook["Mira"]);

Comment: As a sanity check, did you actually call this function as well? Your phoneBook object starts as an empty object with nothing in it.

Comment: I was not lol. I am a beginner as you can see. I got it now after I called the function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly have the right idea.

Two suggestions:

1. you want to use `numbers.length` or `names.length` as the number of iterations
2. you probably don't want to mutate a global object

A working example would look something like this:

```
const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];
const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675'];

function populate(names, numbers) {
    const phoneBook = {};

    for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        phoneBook[names[i]] = numbers[i];
    }

    return phoneBook;
}

const phoneBook = populate(names, numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

More concisely, zip the arrays together, then pass that to `Object.fromEntries(0`

```js
function makePhoneBook(names, numbers) {
  const entries = names.map((name, i) => [name, numbers[i]]);
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}

const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];
const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675']
const phoneBook = makePhoneBook(names, numbers);
console.log(phoneBook);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the note, **[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject)** if you don't mind:

```js
const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];
const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675'];

const phoneBook = _.zipObject(names, numbers);

console.log(phoneBook);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And, of course, one-liner:

```js
const names = ['Mira', 'Royce', 'Kathie'];
const numbers = ['3234958675', '9164059384', '4154958675'];

const phoneBook = names.reduce((acc, name, i) => (acc[name] = numbers[i], acc), {});

console.log(phoneBook);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```